# Android: Text container width inside a button

Tags: android, button, text

I try to do a custom keyboard, so I have a small buttons and the text doesn't fit in my buttons, but it have a few pixels for it:

[image]

Can I increase text container width inside my buttons?

Comment: have you tried playing with padding and margins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

set button Paddings to zero:

```
button.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
```

(I dont really know how custom keyboards work but you may try using TextViews instead of Buttons, and you can set your Image or Background to your TextView aswell. Can use pressed states with selectors and etc...)

Or you can make your own class, and @Override their onDraw method to draw your own text(or charachter) for your view.

As far as i know there are no specific methods to increase text container.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using ImageButton instead of an ordinary Button as keyboard buttons. As you will have the freedom to edit the image the way you want to.